# TextView in LinearLayout not wrapping and going under ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-cardview

There are many similar questions for which the solution is adding layout_weight="1" to the text view. I tried that but it didn't help me. My scenario is different. Don't consider it duplicate.

Below is the layout which I wanted to make. TextView should wrap if there is an image in the image view. If there is no image, it should be as it is.

[image]

Below is the code I tried so far

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
app:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="some text here"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="some text here which should wrap depending upon
            the string length and also considering whether or not there is an image adjacent to it"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="some text here"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/save"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Below is the result of this code. TextView is going under the ImageView without wrapping.

[image]

Is my approach wrong. Could someone help me solve this. I'm using AndroidStudio 3.0 developing with min api level 21(if at all this matters).
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work exactly what you need. You don't need relative layout. change this relative layout with linearlayout as horizontal. then change vertical linearlayout width 0dp and add weight: 1

**XML Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="some text here"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="some text here which should wrap depending upon
            the string length and also considering whether or not there is an image adjacent to it"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="some text here"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It is working. But can you explain this thing.  why this happens and magic of layout_weight

Comment: horizontal linearlayout have two childeren one vertical linearlayout and another image. we set vertical linearlayout as weight: 1 that means it will take 100% space all time because imageview has no weight. but when image is available it will take 100% space except image space and when image not  available it will take 100% space of it's parent without image.

Answer (score 1):

Change the RelativeLayout to LinearLayout and add orientation as horizontal.
If it still not works, add weight to ImageView. It should work .

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need relative layout.

You should use this linear layout 5 times.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="some text here which should wrap depending upon
        the string length and also considering whether or not there is an image adjacent to it"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

If there is no picture the textview it will work as you want
[image]